# Run a Batch Job after successfull completion of first Batch job

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 batch files. I need to start the second Batch job only after **successful completion** of first batch job. if error then the second file will not run.

Comment: How do you indicate first batch job is successful or not ? Please show the batch job contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `&&`. This operator concatenates two commands but executes the second one only if the first one was successfull. This is explained [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html).

So in your case the code would be like this:

```
call first.bat&&call second.bat
```